# Angular 8 HostListener 'window:unload' how to make API call before unload

Tags: angular, synchronous, angular-httpclient

I am using HostListener to detect when a user reloads or closes a browser window. The purpose is to #1 check if the current user owns the 'Is Being Edited' lock on the record, and #2 if so, call an observable to update the database. (Note: I have already implemented the lock system for navigation away from the component using CanDeactivate. The use of HostListener is for specifically reloading or closing the browser window).

According to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window), `'window:unload'` is a synchronous only event, therefore I can't use the asynchronous API call in the body of the host listener.

However, the accepted solution using `XMLHttpRequest()` is [being deprecated according to Mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 /
>   SeaMonkey 2.27), Blink 39.0, and Edge 13, synchronous requests on the
>   main thread have been deprecated due to their negative impact on the
>   user experience.

I need a solution that is more reliable. Is there a way to send a SYNCHRONOUS api call in Angular to work around this limitation? Or is there another way to make sure the API call completes before the browser is reloaded or closed?

```
  // @HostListener allows guard against browser refresh, close, etc.
  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnloadHander($event) {
    // Check if Is Being Edited must be removed
    if (this.mustReleaseIsBeingEdited()) {
      this.updateIsBeingEditedSub = this.updateIsBeingEdited$(true).subscribe(result => {
        return true;
      }, err => { console.error(err); }, () => { });

    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }


  private updateIsBeingEdited$(isBeingEdited): Observable<boolean> {

    const editedObj = {
      _id: this.record._id,
      IsBeingEdited: isBeingEdited,
      EditedBy: this.accessLevelService.getUserId()
    }

    return this.httpService!.postData(
      `records/_id/${editedObj._id}/IsBeingEdited/`,
      editedObj
    );

  }
```

**UPDATE**

I am researching and may have found a [possible solution with sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Adapting_Sync_XHR_usecases_to_the_Beacon_API). I am not sure how to implement this in Angular, or if it is a recommended practice. Any suggestions?

> To solve this problem, analytics and diagnostics code have
>   historically made a synchronous XMLHttpRequest call in an unload or
>   beforeunload event handler to submit the data. The synchronous
>   XMLHttpRequest blocks the process of unloading the document, which in
>   turn causes the next navigation appear to be slower.
>
> This is where sendBeacon() comes in. By using the sendBeacon() method,
>   the data is transmitted asynchronously to the web server when the User
>   Agent has an opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or
>   affecting the performance of the next navigation. This solves all of
>   the problems with submission of analytics data: the data is sent
>   reliably, it's sent asynchronously, and it doesn't impact the loading
>   of the next page.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this with [navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Adapting_Sync_XHR_usecases_to_the_Beacon_API)

> Using the sendBeacon() method, the data will be transmitted
>   asynchronously to the web server when the User Agent has had an
>   opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or affecting the
>   performance of the next navigation.

A second possible solution is to [send the request via the fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131973/need-authorization-in-a-navigator-sendbeacon) with `keepalive` set to true.

Here is the solution that I have tested with sendBeacon().

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(): void {
    /**
     * Post a single object to the server
     * Send Beacon API to keep request after browser windowunload event
     */
    navigator.sendBeacon(`${this.env.apiUrl}/id/${this.id}`);
  }
```