# How to send a POST request via Angular HttpClient wihout cancelling on unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I need to send a POST request and I do not care if it succeeds or fails => "fire and forget". Immediately after sending the request a hard redirect is initiated. This causes the Angular HttpClient POST request to be cancelled.

```
// sending POST request
this.httpClient.post('someUrl', {}).subscribe();
// hard redirect causes cancelation of POST request
window.location.replace('someOtherUrl');
```

Is there any way to send the request without it being cancelled?

Comment: Angular doesn't cancel http request when you manually navigate to a different URL. I guess you're navigating to a completely different domain and it's the browser canceling the request.

Comment: @martin That is my guess as well. I will probably have to wait for the request to complete before navigating.

Comment: You could solve this with a beacon maybe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

Comment: @MikeOne this sounds very interesting. I will look into it! Thanks!

Comment: Sadly the Beacon API does not allow to pass Authorization Header information and thus is not suitable for my usecase (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131973/need-authorization-in-a-navigator-sendbeacon).  But thanks for the link, I had never heard of the API before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `finalize`

```
this.httpClient.post('someUrl', {})
  .pipe(finalize(() => window.location.replace('someOtherUrl'))
  .subscribe();
```

or `add`

```
this.httpClient.post('someUrl', {})
  .subscribe()
  .add(() => window.location.replace('someOtherUrl'));
```

Finalize will emit for `next` or `error`, `add` should be called on unsubscribe (HttpClient automatically completes).

Comment: Thanks, there is probably no way to do this without waiting for the observable to complete, right?

Comment: @wederer With the way browsers handle security, even if you could find a workaround, I wouldn't trust it to work across browsers or into the future. Generally, once a browser navigates away from your domain, all bets are off for how it handles ongoing/midflight requests.